# Access forbidden for file on xampp server

Tags: php, xampp, access-denied

I'm using xampp on mac osx for developing a php web app. I'm using the Yii MVC framework to build the app. I'm trying to access a php file via an ajax function and I keep getting this error

Access Forbidden: You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

So the php file with the ajax function in it is in the same folders as the php file that it's trying to access. I've set the folder to chmod 777, which I assumed would probably do nothing anyway, I was right.

Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: can you directly access the other php file from browser?

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly a problem on your Apache configuration. Maybe you can't access this directory? Have a look to you .htaccess file(s), or the virtual host config

Comment: "it is in the same folders as the php file"

Comment: I found a couple of htaccess files, not sure exactly what I'm looking for in them though. What should I be changing, if anything?

Comment: Can you access to an other PHP file inside this folder, using the browser? If so, it's probably not a .htaccess problem...